# Making charting in C

Tags: c, charts

How do I make [`charts`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chart) in C language? do I need to learn X11/OpenGL or equivalents and advanced math knowledge either there is a lib to do it for me? the requeriments is be written in C,portable(UNIX/Windows) and allow use in proprietary software not open source.

By assuming doing by X11/OpenGL/Allegro etc how hard is this? I've never touched at such libraries.

Another question that come to my mind now: It's possible do it by using Gtk+?

Comment: You definitely need a graphics library of some sort. Way back when we were in school we used calls to gnuplot. I believe gnuplot was made for that very purpose.

Comment: I know about gnuplot. But can I embed it in my proprietary program?

Comment: I would suggest talking with a lawyer but as long as you release any changes to gnuplot itself, you should be able to distribute it with your product. I believe it uses a GPL license.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use GNU Plot. It has [C API](http://ndevilla.free.fr/gnuplot/).

Comment: I just love when someone takes your comment and makes an answer out of it. Makes me want to vote the answer down. But I will resist the urge.

Comment: @Codeguy007 I'm very sorry you believe I have "stolen" your comment to have +1 to my "reputation". If you think I am such a douchebag - flag my comment, and let karma/moderators/etc care about this.

Comment: I don't really care. It's just happened a few times so I made a commit.